# Tweening variable on mouseleave not functioning

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseleave, tween.js

I am attempting to tween a variable down to zero on mouseleave, but nothing happens when the mouse leaves the container.

I have tried various things. What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the code:

```
 function ondocumentMouseLeave ( event ){


            new TWEEN.Tween( mouseY )
            .to ( 0 , 500 )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
            .start();


            new TWEEN.Tween( mouseX )
            .to ( 0 , 500)
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
            .start();
            }
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cxp8rex2/16/

I apologize if this is a simple question, I am a bit new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an **Object** and tween its properties like:

```
function ondocumentMouseLeave ( event ) {

  var mouse = {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};

  new TWEEN.Tween( mouse ).to ( { x: 500, y: 500 }, 1000 )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None )
    .onUpdate(function() {
        mouseX = this.x;
        mouseY = this.y;
    })
    .start();

}
```

have a look on [tween.js user guide](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md).

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly! I have an additional question, could I use this method to animate on mouseenter as well or would that conflict with my current mousemove function? Instead of popping when you enter the frame i would like it to animate to your current mouse location...I tried delaying mousemove until after mousenter, but if you move fast enough it still pops.

Comment: I updated your demo and removed tween.js https://jsfiddle.net/cxp8rex2/20/ and changed the render method. Check if it is what you have in mind. Cheers

Comment: this works flawlessly. Thank you so much. I assume "+=" means to  increment from the last calculation?

Comment: you are right. **x += newValue;** is a short hand to: **x = x + newValue;** have a look on [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)